# Auto re connect to WiFi on connection drop using Python 3 on Raspbian

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I've created an UI using RPi and used GPIO to collect data from a remote machine and send that data through the WiFi. I made all the scripting using Python 3 and i want to add a function or something to auto reconnect to  a 'specified WiFi network'. I don't want to search for available networks, i just want to keep trying to reconnect to that one particular WiFi network. Like after every 'n' seconds, try to re connect. This network wouldn't have internet access btw, just trying to send data to a local server.

Tried all similar scripts from all possible similar threads but to of no use. If someone could give lead, it would be great, thanks!

Comment: If you have working script in python to create a WiFi connection, you can add it to crontab and define the repeat interval(s) there.  Every second: `* * * * * /path/to/python/python /path/to/my/python/script/script.py` Just be sure, that `sudo crontab` and that `su`/`pi` user has access rights to the paths.

Comment: Uhm, I don't have a working script to create the WiFi re connection, any idea about that?

Comment: Have you checked this one (how to setup WiFi in RPi)? RPi should connect automatically, if configured WiFi hotspot is available (no python script needed). http://weworkweplay.com/play/automatically-connect-a-raspberry-pi-to-a-wifi-network/ Then you could check, if wlan0 has IP address with os.subprocess() and if true, do the trick. Set this access point as only WiFi access point in RPi.

Comment: I want to do it using Python only @Mika72

Comment: If your wifi connection drop from time to time, it means that your wifi connection is weak, not stable or subject to interference. You should solve it on the connection level rather than trying to use an application to reconnect it.